# Video software photo collage

Tags: video, software-design

I'm wondering which video software was used to produce this video. Any tips?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnmIBgc-fAk

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe After Effects. My tip: learn it. Another tip: better questions get better answers.